# Date field not saved using rails 3.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an ActiveRecord and when i click on save all records are saved except the date.

My contorller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def create
  puts params[:user]
   @user1 = User.new(params[:user])
   if @user1.save
    saveduser = User.where("fbid = ?",params[:user][:fbid])
    unless saveduser.first.nil?
    session[:user] = saveduser.first
   end
   puts "user saved "
  redirect_to "/users/dashboard"
  else
    puts "error while saving user"
  end  
 end
```

The view

```
<h3>User Details</h3>
 <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<table>
  --some columns
<tr>
  <td><%= f.label :state %></td>
  <td> <%= f.text_field :state %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><%= f.label :dob %></td>
  <td> <%= f.text_field :dob %></td>
</tr>
  <%= f.hidden_field :fbid  %>
 </table> 
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
<table>
```

In console when create method is called in UserController . I can see

```
{"username"=>"xxxx.xx.94", "firstname"=>"xxxx", "lastname"=>"Raxxstogi", "emaild"=>"xx.xxx@gmail.com", "city"=>"Los Angeles", "country"=>"USA", "state"=>"CA", "dob"=>"08/13/1983", "fbid"=>"xxx"}
```

My DB table column is

`dob        | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |`

Where is it going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a `text_field` in your form to save into a `Date` type field in the DB.  Try instead to use the date helper methods as described here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#using-date-and-time-form-helpers

Comment: ok the date_select works.. by default its set to today's date.. i need to figure how to set correct value..

Answer (score 2):

Ruby doesn't understand your date format. You can fix this by explicitly parsing the date with [`Date::strptime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime), perhaps in the model as a setter method:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def dob=(date)
    date = Date.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y') if date.is_a?(String)
    write_attribute(:dob, date)
  end
end
```

I would, however, second jordanpg's recommendation to use the date helpers in Rails, unless you know that the format will be the same every time.

Answer (score 0):

it could be the problem with your date format. You can either configure active record to accept this format or convert your date param to Date object using strftime or something like it